# Best way to defend against mysql injection and cross site scripting

Tags: php, sql, security, xss

At the moment, I apply a 'throw everything at the wall and see what sticks' method of stopping the aforementioned issues. Below is the function I have cobbled together:

```
function madSafety($string)
{

$string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
$string = stripslashes($string);
$string = strip_tags($string);
return $string;

}
```

However, I am convinced that there is a better way to do this. I am using FILTER_ SANITIZE_STRING and this doesn't appear to to totally secure.

I guess I am asking, which methods do you guys employ and how successful are they? Thanks

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php

Comment: This approach is wrong on so many aspects! I've posted an answer below and rated each of the responses -1 for their authors refuse to think.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just doing a lot of stuff that you don't really understand, is not going to help you. You need to understand what injection attacks are and exactly how and where you should do what.

In bullet points:

- [Disable magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php). They are an inadequate solution, and they confuse matters.
- Never embed strings directly in SQL. Use bound parameters, or escape (using `mysql_real_escape_string`).
- **Don't** unescape (eg. `stripslashes`) when you retrieve data from the database.
- When you embed strings in html (Eg. when you `echo`), you should default to escape the string (Using `htmlentities` with `ENT_QUOTES`).
- If you need to embed html-strings in html, you must consider the source of the string. If it's untrusted, you should pipe it through a filter. `strip_tags` is in theory what you should use, but it's flawed; Use [HtmlPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) instead.

See also: [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Comment: Excellent - this is significantly better than the response I was writing, now abandoned. +1

Answer (score 10):

The best way against SQL injection is to bind variables, rather then "injecting" them into string.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Be carefully with allowable tags - pretty well any tag can have JS embedded into it.

Comment: Also - see http://isisblogs.poly.edu/2008/08/16/php-strip_tags-not-a-complete-protection-against-xss/

Comment: strip_tags is flawed .. escape strings, or if you really need to allow html, use htmlpurifier

Answer (score 3):

**Don’t**!  Using `mysql_real_escape_string` is enough to protect you against SQL injection and the `stropslashes` you are doing *after* makes you vulnerable to SQL injection.  If you really want it, put it *before* as in:

```
function madSafety($string)
{
    $string = stripslashes($string);
    $string = strip_tags($string);
    $string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
    return $string;
}
```

`stripslashes` is not really useful if you are doing `mysql_real_escape_string`.

`strip_tags` protects against HTML/XML injection, not SQL.

The important thing to note is that you should escape your strings *differently* depending on the imediate use you have for it.

When you are doing MYSQL requests use `mysql_real_escape_string`.  When you are outputing web pages use `htmlentities`.  To build web links use `urlencode`…

As vartec noted, if you can use placeholders by all means do it.

Comment: Actually, mysql_real_escape_string is not entirely safe either. See http://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html

Answer (score 1):

This topic is so wrong!

You should NOT filter the input of the user! It is information that has been entered by him. What are you going to do if I want my password be like: `'"'>s3cr3t<script>alert()</script>`

Filter the characters and leave me with a changed password, so I cannot even succeed in my first login? This is bad.

The proper solution is to use prepared statements or `mysql_real_escape_string()` to avoid sql injections and use context-aware escaping of the characters to avoid your html code being messed up.

Let me remind you that the web is only one of the ways you can represent the information entered by the user. Would you accept such stripping if some desktop software do it? I hope your answer is NO and you would understand why this is not the right way.

Note that in different context different characters has to be escaped. For example, if you need to display the user first name as a tooltip, you will use something like:

```
<span title="{$user->firstName}">{$user->firstName}</span>
```

However, if the user has set his first name to be like `'"><script>window.document.location.href="http://google.com"</script>` what are you gonna do? Strip the quotes? This would be so wrong! Instead of doing this non-sense, consider escaping the quotes while rendering the data, not while persisting it!

Another context you should consider is while rendering the value itself. Consider the previously used html code and imagine the user first name be like `<textarea>`. This would wrap all html code that follows into this textarea element, thus breaking up the whole page.

Yet again - consider escaping the data depending on the context you are using it in!

P.S Not really sure how to react on those negative votes. Are you, people, actually reading my reply?

Comment: Instead of having my comment deleted, please try to understand what I was saying. If a user had a username with tags like that I wouldn't strip the tags, I would reject the username entirely and force them to come up with a username that's less, forgive me, stupid. Passwords would be different, sure, but usernames with `<script>` in them? Reject it.

Comment: I have not deleted your comment. I flagged it and someone decided the flag was appropriate.

What the user inputs is none of my business, I take care for my application to function properly. Making sense of data and escaping the data are two radically different things. Please, don't have the two mixed up.

You can have whatever you want as a username, nor the presentation layer (html), nor the persistence layer (mysql, postgre, etc) have to stand in your way.

Again, the question is how to escape the data, not how to filter or apply censorship to it.