# Error in SQL UPDATE query

Tags: php, sql, mysql

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE categories
        SET cd_title='$docuTitle' , cd_link='$linkTitle'
        WHERE c_name='$catID'");
```

What is wrong with this update query?

Comment: The query looks fine. Please be more specific.

Comment: What's the error given? mysql_error () should output it.

Comment: Are your variables properly escaped?

Answer (score 2):

There is probably something wrong with the data in your variables — but we can't see what they contain.

You should be using parameterized queries, which would deal with any odd characters in your data that might mess up the statement.

See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php) and [When are the most recommended times to use mysql_real_escape_string()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723945/when-are-the-most-recommended-times-to-use-mysqlrealescapestring)

Answer (score 0):

I would change the query to this, to avoid errors if input contains apostrophes:

```
$result = mysql_query(
    "UPDATE categories SET
         cd_title='" . mysql_real_escape_string($docuTitle) . "',
         cd_link='" . mysql_real_escape_string($linkTitle) . "'
     WHERE
         c_name='" . mysql_real_escape_string($catID) . "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is sanitized, remove the single quotes from around the php variables.