# Best way to escape strings for sql inserts?

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, sql-injection, sanitization

What is the best way to escape strings for sql inserts, updates?

I want to allow special characters including ' and ".  Is the best way to search and replace each string before I use it in an insert statement?

Thanks

Duplicate of: [Best way to defend against mysql injection and cross site scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568995/best-way-to-defend-against-mysql-injection-and-cross-site-scripting)

Comment: Why do you need to do any parsing? Doesn't mysql permit parameterized queries?

Comment: By 'parse', do you mean to say 'escape', that is, neutralize metacharacters so that data can be safely embedded in a query?

Comment: Okay.  Editing question pursuant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using parameterized queries (so by extension, a DB interface library that supports parameterized queries) so that SQL injection can't happen.

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about data values for your fields, then the best way is to use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://us.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).  (Some people like [mysqli](http://us.php.net/mysqli); can't say I do.)  If you're talking about allowing user-submitted queries... well, let's hope you're not talking about that.