# how to update my url column in sql which has & in string

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle

```
update <table> set url="http://www.google.com?a=1&something=so"
```

If I'm updating directly my string is updated till ?a=1 from & it is eliminating. can any one help me in this if my url contains any special symbol and how I need to update. I'm working from java

Comment: Try to use 'single quotes'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to escape strings for sql inserts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633109/best-way-to-escape-strings-for-sql-inserts)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid problems with string values consider using `PreparedStatement` and its `setString` method which will generate proper query with escaped values (if needed).

So try with

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("update table set url=?");
//           +----------------------------------------------------^
//           | represents where we should put value
ps.setString(1, "http://www.google.com?a=1&something=so");

//then execute this statement
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:-

update [table_name] set url='http://www.google.com?a=1'||'&'||'something=so'

here we are concatenating &, so that it does not create problem while update.

FYI.. if we have & in the string we try to update, oracle consider string following & as a parameter whose value it thinks as if it will be provided at run time, that is the reason why it was troubling you.