# PHP, receiving POST'd sql in a php script, getting some mysql errors, should I be using addslashes?

Tags: php

In most cases whenan sql update query is posted my php script, it works without problem. However, in some cases I get an error from mysql. I'm using a encryption function to send data over the net, so it arrives as sent.

If I post the same query into phpmyadmin, it always works.

Do I need to add $sql = addslashes($sql); ?

I'm hesitant to use this on all queries as most of the work and I don't want to end up with slashes in my data when it may not be needed.

Comment: adding slashes to the entire query is a nonsense. why not to read some manual before using a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mysql_real_escape_string](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

ex:

```
$c = mysql_connect("localhost","a","b");
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE name="%s";'
mysql_query(sprintf($query,mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'],$c)));
```

Comment: Can I use mysql_real_escape_string() on the full sql statement ?

Comment: Shortly: No. Because you'd also be escaping the quotes which belong into the query.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is useless in his case. addslashes is enough

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Changing this to addslashes barely gives any performance boost, but might lead to leaks later. I'd still stick with mysql_escape

Comment: looooooooooooool. who is talking of "performance"? He does create his query *on the another host*. Try to think of it while keeping in mind how does mysql_real_escape_string work.

Comment: You might want to state your point directly without trying to be witty.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string does take current database connection character set into account. But the OP does build his query on the another host. Thus, there is no use of mysql_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying what error exactly you get from mySQL. (Please always, always add the error message and example data.)

I'm going to guess though that the SQL query breaks when the user enters quotes: `'` or `"`

This is a sign of a very dangerous vulnerability called [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection-closed).

Do not use addslashes() to fix it, but the escaping method provided by your database layer - probably `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

More info: [Best way to defend against mysql injection and cross site scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568995/best-way-to-defend-against-mysql-injection-and-cross-site-scripting)

Comment: he is adding slashes to the entire query, lol. I won't be surprised if he sends a query itself

Comment: I'm not sure what the error is, I don't log it. But it will be due to ' or "" or maybe \. My other system builds up the sql. So theres little danger of sql injection. Could I use mysql_real_escape_string() on my whole sql query ?

Comment: @Jules no, you need to escape the values only

Comment: @Jules you also want to start logging (or at least displaying) your errors - it'll make your work much easier