# A PHP function to prevent SQL Injections and XSS

Tags: php, mysql, xss, sql-injection

I am tring to make my PHP as secure as possible, and the two main things I am trying to avoid are

- mySQL Injections
- Cross-Side Scripting (XSS)

---

This is the script I got against mySQL Injections:

```
function make_safe($variable) {
$variable = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($variable)); 
return $variable;  }
```

http://www.addedbytes.com/writing-secure-php/writing-secure-php-1/

---

Against XSS, I found this:

```
$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
```

---

Now I want to unite the two into a single function. Would this be the best way to do so? :

```
function make_safe($variable) {
$variable = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($variable)));
return $variable; }
```

Or does the **mysql_real_escape_string** already prevent XSS? And lastly, is there anything else that I could add into this function to prevent other forms of hacking?

Comment: There is no magic wand, just constant vigilance.

Comment: You and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) should become friends!

Comment: I don't really understand what the two of you are saying ;)

Comment: You should find some useful info in the answers to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568995/best-way-to-defend-against-mysql-injection-and-cross-site-scripting) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) doesn't prevent XSS. It will only make impossible to do SQL injections.

To fight XSS, you need to use [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). 1st will convert special chars like `<` to `&lt;` that will show up as `<`, but won't be executed. 2nd just strip all tags out.

I don't recommend to make special function to do it or even make one function to do it all, but your given example would work. I assume.

Comment: And can't I use only strip_tags(), making htmlspecialchars() redundant?

Comment: Might be good to mention `mysql_real_escape_string()` is deprecated and has been replaced by `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

Answer (score 14):

This function:

```
function make_safe($variable) 
{
   $variable = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($variable)));
   return $variable; 
}
```

**Will not work**

SQL injection and XSS are two different beasts. Because they each require different escaping you need to use each escape function `strip_tags` and `mysql_real_escape_string` separatly.
Joining them up will defeat the security of each.

Use the standard `mysql_real_escape_string()` when inputting data into the database.
Use `strip_tags()` when querying stuff out of the database before outputting them to the screen.

**Why combining the two function is dangerous**
From the horses mouth: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

> Because strip_tags() does not actually validate the HTML, partial or broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected.

So by inputting malformed html into a database field a smart attacker can use your naive implementation to defeat `mysql_real_escape_string()` in your combo.

Comment: So I use mysql_real_escape_string() when adding data to the database, but not when comparing user input with database entries (like when loggin in)?

Comment: @user, You use `mysql_real_escape_string()` **always**, on every query, be it select, update delete or insert.

Answer (score 2):

What you should really be looking into is using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) to both provide an abstraction layer against your database as well as completely eradicate SQL injection attacks.

As for XSS, just make sure to never trust user input. Either run [strip_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) or [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) when you store the data, or when you output it (not both as this will mess with your output), and you'll be all right.

Comment: I've never heard of PDO. What is that?

Comment: PDO is a database abstraction layer included with PHP. Have a look here for an introduction: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/