# Form validation. Is $_POST if NOT null possible?

Tags: php, forms, validation

Is it possible to tell php to NOT post data if the form field is null?

right now my post variables in my insert.php page look like this:

```
fname = $_POST['firstname'];
lname = $_post['lasname'];

sql = "UPDATE profile SET first='.$fname.', last='.$lname.' WHERE id='.$id.'";
```

---

If my form fields are empty or null, I'd like the $fname $lname not to post. What would be the best method to do this?

Currently when i submit an update, if those fields are empty they update the entire table with empty rows if nothing is inserted.

Comment: you would have to remove the form field before being submitted for them to not be included in the $_POST array

Comment: I think that your question is meant by Javascript rather than PHP

Comment: Ahoy, SQL injection ahead! Use parameterized queries with PDO or MySQLi!

Comment: Why those dots inside double quoted strings?

Comment: Clarification: do you want to *insert NULL values* or do you want to *not execute* the query? Or is something else desired ..?

Comment: No... i would like to NOT post fields that do not have values. I would like to update only the data whose fields have something in them.

Comment: You'll need some extra query logic to do that.

Comment: hey... i know the syntax is wrong. i drafted it up quickly just to see if i can get some help with hidding or not posting empty fields :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this for each field:

```
$fname = empty($_POST['firstname']) ? null : $_POST['firstname'];
```

This will set `$fname` to null if the form field does not exist or the input was empty. Otherwise, it will use the original value.

#### Update

If you want to only update fields that aren't null, you'll need to add some extra logic:

```
if($fname !== null && $lname !== null) {
    // update both
}
else if($fname !== null) {
    // update just fname
}
else if($lname !== null) {
    // update just lname
}
```

Comment: Due to the current approach (no placeholders), this won't work. Also, I'm not sure if the poster is asking to insert NULL or doesn't want to update at all..

Comment: I think that's a separate issue with the query itself.

Comment: Of course, but that should be taken into account: "Due to the current approach (no placeholders), this *won't work*". At the very least this should be explained.

Comment: If the OP modifies their question, I'll modify my answer :)

Comment: Regardless of if the poster modifies the question, this is *still currently wrong* and/or incomplete.

Comment: I can't see how this will work. Seems like if anything it will update my field with an empty value? Is it possible to just ignore the row altogether thru PHP if nothing is entered?

Comment: Have a look at my edit. You need to adjust your SQL depending on the state of the variables.

Comment: It's questions like these that tend to put everyone/anyone answering, into a `minus` factor.

Answer (score 0):

`Is it possible to tell php to NOT post data if the form field is null?`
It isn't PHP who is posting data, it is your browser the moment you hit the submit button of the form. In order to prevent this from happening when the fields are empty, you will have to use something client-sided (javascript), which first validates if the fields are indeed filled in before the form is submitted.

This is how I understand your question though. If you don't want to create the SQL query when the `$_POST` variables are empty, then simply use an if condition or a ternary operator.

Comment: Sounds easy enough but how would i tell Javascript to hide values that are null? It's above my head...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Javascript works client-sided and what you're asking here is something server-sided I guess. If you don't want the form to post at all if the fields are empty, you'll need javascript. If you want something done after the form is posted, you need PHP. What exactly do you want to get done? What is the expected behaviour? Clarify your original question a bit, as you can see the answers broadly differ due to the vagueness of the question.

Comment: Before the form is submitted, hide the unchanged fields. The null or empty fields only. Currently when i submit an update, if those fields are empty they update the entire table with empty rows if nothing is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```
$fname = isset($_POST['firstname']) && strlen($_POST['firstname']) > 0 ? $_POST['firstname'] : null;
```

This way, $fname will be defined to the $_POST['firstname'] value if the variable is set and not empty, otherwise it will be `null`

By the way, if you're working inside double quotes (`"`), there's no need to use a dot to add values to the $sql string. Even more, your syntax is wrong. This is a working way to do it:

```
$sql = "UPDATE profile SET first='$fname', last='$lname' WHERE id='$id'";
```

You should **NOT** use this kind of SQL-query generation. It's vulnerable to SQL injections. Better use **PDO** or **MySQLi** parametrized queries.

And, by the way, if you want to deny the insertion if a value is empty, you better do it when creating the MySQL table (assigning a `not null` property to the column). For example:

```
CREATE TABLE user(
    first VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    last VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

** EDIT: If I'm understanding well, this is that you want:

```
$valuesToAdd = "";
// Concatenate values to the query if they are defined
if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && strlen($_POST['firstname']) > 0) $valuesToAdd .= "first = '{$_POST['firstname']}',";
if (isset($_POST['lastname']) && strlen($_POST['lastname']) > 0) $valuesToAdd .= "last = '{$_POST['lastname']}',";
// Repeat for any other values...

// By default, the SQL string is empty
$sql = "";

// If changes were made...
if (strlen($valuesToAdd) > 0) {
    // Remove the last ","
    $valuesToAdd = substr($valuesToAdd, 0, strlen($valuesToAdd)-1);

    // Generate the SQL string with the values which will be added
    $sql = "UPDATE profile SET {$valuesToAdd} WHERE id='{$id}'";

    // echo $sql; die;
}


// Check if the SQL string is not empty
if (strlen($sql) > 0) {
    // Here the SQL has been generated, use it for a SQL query...
    // $con = mysql_connect(...); .....
}
```

Comment: The use of `isset()` is redundant; the check is included in `empty()`.

Comment: For the sake of time, and not wanting to copy my entire insert.php page, i quickly drafted the above. so if i am correct, isset would replace my $_POST variables?

Comment: No, isset is used for a conditional assignation. For example, `$v = isset($a) ? $a : null;` is equivalent to `if ( isset($a) ) $v = $a; else $v = null;`, but the "avoid inserting empty values" is better to be done in MySQL rather than PHP (you'll be ensuring consistency of your database).

Comment: Well... what i did is, created a form which submits some profile information. I then duplicated that form and made it an update page. This page fetches the associated id of the profile and updates the record. The problem is, is when u submit a field with changes, the others are deleted.

Comment: You should not use `empty` in these case. Otherwise the user will not be able to store values such as `0` and `0.0` in database.

Comment: ok i just tried this but it didnt work :-( there are syntax errors and some other issues. gonna see what other options are out there.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `$valuesToAdd = substr($valuesToAdd, 0, strlen($valuesToAdd)-1);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lname = $_POST['lastname'];

$sets = array();

if(trim($fname)) {
  $sets[] = "first = '".mysql_real_escape_string($fname)."'";
}
if(trim($lname)) {
  $sets[] = "last = '".mysql_real_escape_string($lname)."'";
}

if($sets) {
  $sql = "UPDATE profile SET ".implode(", ", $sets)." WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."'";
}
```

Remember to properly escape your values before you glue them to SQL.

Comment: what exactly does this do?

Comment: @MizAkita Takes values that came from browser in POST. If they are not empty, escapes them and attaches them to database field names. Then merges them into single query. Basically, what you wanted to do but without vulnerability to SQL injection.

Answer (score -1):

You need form validation. Easy solution will not allow empty fields save in db and prevent [SQL-injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

**Easy solution**:

```
$fname = isset($_POST['firstname']) and nameIsValid($_POST['firstname'])
    ? $_POST['firstname'] : false;
$lname = isset($_POST['lastname']) and nameIsValid($_POST['lastname'])
    ? $_POST['lastname'] : false;

if (false === $fname or false === $lname) {
    // report about not valid form fields
} else {
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=yourdb;host=yourhost;charset=utf8';
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, 'user', 'pass');
    $sql = "UPDATE profile SET first = :fname, last = :lname WHERE id = :id";

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':fname' => $value, ':lname' => $lname, ':id' => $id));
}

/**
 * Validation names for empty values
 *
 * @param string $name First name or last name
 * @return bool
 */
function nameIsValid($name) {
    return '' !== $name;
}
```

But be aware of [XSS-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857817/a-php-function-to-prevent-sql-injections-and-xss). For example somebody can save in your db Fist name:

```
<script>alert('Woohoo! You have vulnerability!');</script>
```

And next time, when you print First name of the user, everyone will see message about vulnerability :)

You may decide implement more strict validation rules, which will not allow names like **"asfyua23807*^2#"**, **"-2*&%$9837239askHF"** or XSS-injections. In this case you should modify `nameIsValid()` function.

**Safe solution:**

```
/**
 * Validation names and prevent XSS-injections
 *
 * @param string $name First name or last name
 * @return bool
 */
function nameIsValid($name) {
    $pattern = '/^[\.a-z-]+$/i';
    return (bool) preg_match($pattern, $name);
}
```

This logic allow names containing A-z . - symbols: **J.Jameson**, **Jackson-Piterson**, **JOHn**, **smIth**, **etc**.
For more strict validation rules check [Official PHP Regular Expressions manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php).

Comment: And what if user's name contains german, chinese, russian characters? Then surely your function `nameIsValid()` would **lie** to you.

Comment: Also, `nameIsValid()` does not prevent XSS since it does only `preg_macth()`. If it were `preg_replace()`, then that description would make sense.

Comment: @DaveJust in couple with proposed logic, YES, this prevent XSS. For german, chinese, russian characters just modify `$pattern` as i noted in my answer: "For more strict validation rules check Official PHP Regular Expressions manual."

Comment: @DaveJust Also, i sad that `$pattern` allow names containing A-z . - symbols. The questioner doesn't said something about german or russian names.

Comment: So, how do you know where your user comes from? He could come from anywhere and his name could contain foreign characters, like `Ü, ß`. **So what's the point?** So, if his name contains, say `ß`, then `nameIsValid()` will return `FALSE`, even if his name is valid. You say that `$pattern` should be modified. Okay, then should it be modified for all languages? **That's a bad solution**. Instead, a black list of characters should be defined and each time you should check if that string contain bad characters.

Comment: To prevent XSS, something like `htmlentities()` would be great enough on data outputing.

Comment: @DaveJust "He could come from anywhere". Hmm.. How do you know this? You see this in question? Can you point me exactly where you found that? May be questioner don't want names like `Üßsaldj`. This is another question **how to validate unicode characters in forms**.

Comment: Yes, this could be another question. But I'm critiquing your **solution**, because **it will be so easy to break** your validation. If you want to test whether name is valid, check 1) its length (max and min) 2) If it does not contain **undesired** characters. Because you're testing characters to find out if they meet your requirements. `preg_match('/^[\.a-z-]+$/i', $name)` is purely bad solution. If you don't believe me, then see how a validation layer is implemented in `ZF2` against values like `$name`. The problem again - you're looking only **for desired characters** when approaching names

Comment: @DaveJust i can accept your point only if questioner will update question for unicode names requirements. Then i'll update solution to unicode variant. But she can update requirements to ASCII names. So, your talk about "bad solution" is pointless.