# Can I use mysql_real_escape_string together with strip_tags?

Tags: php, mysql-real-escape-string, strip-tags

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I currently have the following and it SEEMS to be working in the browser, but Dreamweaver is telling me there is a syntax error:

```
$formdescription = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['form_description']));
```

Comment: In what way is Dreamweaver telling you about the syntax error?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568995/best-way-to-defend-against-mysql-injection-and-cross-site-scripting

Comment: + Dreamweaver is a liar... it's not a bad IDE for most things but there are better ones out there for PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's ok :) Forget Dreamweaver!

You can also split the above:

```
$formdescription = $_POST['form_description'];
$formdescription = strip_tags($formdescription);
$formdescription = mysql_real_escape_string($formdescription);
```

Comment: before use any method must look to it's core documentation for any updates, mysql_real_escape_string() is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future use mysqli_real_escape_string() instead.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 2):

```
string mysql_real_escape_string ( string $unescaped_string [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

operation of this function depends on the encoding of the current mysql connection, you must pass the second parameter `[, resource $link_identifier = NULL ]` to avoid warnings in DW.

Comment: +1 This does seem to fix it, you can pass `NULL` if you don't want to worry about passing the resource around.