# Insert Posted PHP array into MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have built the array below to insert multiple rows that is passed from a multi row html form into a MYSQL Database. What I am running into and cannot figure out is how to modify what I have already built to insert multiple rows correctly. I have provided the code and examples below.

```
   <?php 
        include 'connect.php'; 
            $records= array(
              'palid' => $_POST['LPN'],
              'auditor' => $_POST['ANAME'],
              'itnum' => $_POST['Part'],
              'ordid' => $_POST['Order'],
              'pckusr' => $_POST['Picker'],
              'expected' => $_POST['Eaches'],
              'actual' => $_POST['Actual']);

    $keys = implode(', ', array_keys($records));

    $col = array();
    foreach ($records as $rowValues) {
        foreach ($rowValues as $key => $rowValue) {
             $rowValues[$key] = $rowValues[$key];
        }

        $col[] = "(" . implode(', ', $rowValues) . ")";
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO audit ($keys) VALUES " . implode (', ', $col);
    echo $query;

  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

  ?>
```

The echo $query; shows the below which is just the values for all three rows of each column concatenated together instead of each individual row concatenated together.

```
    INSERT INTO audit(palid, auditor, itnum, ordid, pckusr, expected, actual) VALUES(0010070382, 0010070382, 0010070382), (aud01, aud01, aud01), (2616M, 2216T, 1216F), (5167-2, 5167-2, 5167-2), (LION, LION, LION), (30, 300, 402), (30, 300, 402)
```

As it should look like this:

```
    INSERT INTO audit(palid, auditor, itnum, ordid, pckusr, expected, actual) VALUES(0010070382, aud01, 2616M, 5167-2, LION, 30, 30), (0010070382, aud01, 2216T, 5167-2, LION, 300, 300), (0010070382, aud01, 1216F, 5167-2, LION, 402, 402)
```

When I use var_dump($records); the array passes the below information, but I have yet to figure out how to form the information into each associated group to pass the three rows into my MYSQL database.

```
    array(7)
    {
        ["palid"] => array(3)
        {
            [0] => string(10) "0010070382"
            [1] => string(10) "0010070382"
            [2] => string(10) "0010070382"
        }
        ["auditor"] => array(3)
        {
            [0] => string(5) "aud01"
            [1] => string(5) "aud01"
            [2] => string(5) "aud01"
        }
        ["itnum"] => array(3)
        {
            [0] => string(5) "2616M"
            [1] => string(5) "2216T"
            [2] => string(5) "1216F"
        }
        ["ordid"] => array(3)
        {
            [0] => string(6) "5167-2"
            [1] => string(6) "5167-2"
            [2] => string(6) "5167-2"
        }
        ["pckusr"] => array(3)
        {
            [0] => string(4) "LION"
            [1] => string(4) "LION"
            [2] => string(4) "LION"
        }
        ["expected"] => array(3)
        {
            [0] => string(2) "30"
            [1] => string(3) "300"
            [2] => string(3) "402"
        }
        ["actual"] => array(3)
        {
            [0] => string(2) "30"
            [1] => string(3) "300"
            [2] => string(3) "402"
        }
    }
```

Comment: dont forget xss http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568995/best-way-to-defend-against-mysql-injection-and-cross-site-scripting?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing this with [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), not just jamming user-provided information into a database query. That's a very bad idea! Try this PDO code:

```
<?php
$db_name = "";
$db_user = "";
$db_pass = "";
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO audit(palid, auditor, itnum, ordid, pckusr, expected, actual) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

// refactor the POST arrays
$recordcount = count($_POST["LPN"]);
for ($i = 0; $i < $recordcount; $i++) {
    $records[] = [
        $_POST["LPN"][$i],
        $_POST["ANAME"][$i],
        $_POST["Part"][$i],
        $_POST["Order"][$i],
        $_POST["Picker"][$i],
        $_POST["Eaches"][$i],
        $_POST["Actual"][$i],
    ];
}

foreach ($records as $record) {
    $stmt->execute($record);
}
```

You're building a query with placeholders `?` for each variable. Within a loop, that query gets executed, which replaces those placeholders with the correct value. This also takes care of escaping any unsafe characters – with your existing code, anyone could easily wipe out your database.

Comment: PDO is really nice for this job since you can name your placeholders. Super easy to rack up a bunch of inserts and `execute` them one by one.

Comment: miken32 You rock. Thanks for the help and the tip about PDO and sql injection.

Answer (score -2):

@miken32 pointed your one of the most important elements for avoiding sql injections this is something that you should definitely use. But here is an solutions that should do the trick for your implementation in case you are just curious how to solve this.

```
    include 'connect.php'; 
    $records= array(
          'palid' => $_POST['LPN'],
          'auditor' => $_POST['ANAME'],
          'itnum' => $_POST['Part'],
          'ordid' => $_POST['Order'],
          'pckusr' => $_POST['Picker'],
          'expected' => $_POST['Eaches'],
          'actual' => $_POST['Actual']
    );

    $col = [];
    $keys = [];
    $valuesForInsert = [];

    foreach ($records as $recordKey => $rowValues) {
        $keys[] = $recordKey;
        foreach ($rowValues as $key => $rowValue) {
            $valuesForInsert[$key][] = $rowValues[$key];
        }
    }

    foreach ($valuesForInsert as $rowValue) {
        $col[] = "(".implode(', ', $rowValue).")";
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO audit ($keys) VALUES ".implode(', ', $col);
    echo $query;
```

Comment: You can't give lip service to SQL injections, then go and completely ignore it in your answer. This just fossilizes the bad code. This can be fixed properly with a `bind_param` call.

Comment: Actually, the answer itself isn't bad I think, you should just emphasize *when* it is acceptable to use. In an environment where you can be sure you are in control of the input, it really doesn't matter. In a public facing or publicly accessible setup, this is a recipe for disast;DROP TABLE COMMENTS

Comment: I think that  when someone is learning something new and he is asking about specific problem that he is trying to solve. I'm trying to follow his vision, why? Because I can tell him, HEY MAN! This should go to controllers and this you should be escaped, this you can put into workers. And ... yes there is so many things that we can change here. But I just answered how to solve this problem in mindset of that question. And as you can see I also pointed out that this code is susceptible for SQLInjections, and it should be covered but, let him take this step by step. Make the learning easier.